# Cannot add custom element to jQuery DataTable header

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I tried to add custom toolbar element (i.e. Checkbox) to the DataTable as indicated on [Custom toolbar elements](https://xcmsonline.scripps.edu/lib/DataTables-1.10.12/examples/advanced_init/dom_toolbar.html) shown below, I cannot display the custom element on the header (there is no error on console). I also changed my javascript and css files with the ones on the example, but it did not make any sense. How can I add a Checkbox on DataTable header?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
    } );

    $("div.toolbar").html('<b>Custom tool bar! Text/images etc.</b>');
} );
```

**Here is what I want to do on the image below:**

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working example? (jsfiddle/snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/SPViradiya/zeacozyc/) ? Or provide your issue with fiddle or something.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
         'columnDefs': [{
         'targets': 0,
         'searchable': false,
         'orderable': false,
         'className': 'dt-body-center',
         'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                   return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
               }
            }],
            "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'
    } );
    
    $("div.toolbar").html('<input type="checkbox" name="demo" /> Get all records');
 
    $('#example-select-all').on('click', function(){
      // Get all rows with search applied
      var rows = table.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
      // Check/uncheck checkboxes for all rows in the table
      $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
   });
} );
```

```css
.toolbar {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://xcmsonline.scripps.edu/lib/DataTables-1.10.12/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://xcmsonline.scripps.edu/lib/DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" name="select_all" value="1" id="example-select-all"></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>2011/07/25</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2009/01/12</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2012/03/29</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>2008/11/28</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2012/12/02</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2012/08/06</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>2010/10/14</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>2009/09/15</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2008/12/13</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2008/12/19</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
            <td>Support Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2013/03/03</td>
            <td>$342,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Charde Marshall</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>36</td>
            <td>2008/10/16</td>
            <td>$470,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
            <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>43</td>
            <td>2012/12/18</td>
            <td>$313,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>2010/03/17</td>
            <td>$385,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Michael Silva</td>
            <td>Marketing Designer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>2012/11/27</td>
            <td>$198,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Paul Byrd</td>
            <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>64</td>
            <td>2010/06/09</td>
            <td>$725,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Gloria Little</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>2009/04/10</td>
            <td>$237,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Bradley Greer</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>41</td>
            <td>2012/10/13</td>
            <td>$132,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Dai Rios</td>
            <td>Personnel Lead</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>35</td>
            <td>2012/09/26</td>
            <td>$217,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
            <td>Development Lead</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2011/09/03</td>
            <td>$345,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Yuri Berry</td>
            <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>40</td>
            <td>2009/06/25</td>
            <td>$675,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Caesar Vance</td>
            <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2011/12/12</td>
            <td>$106,450</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Doris Wilder</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>2010/09/20</td>
            <td>$85,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>47</td>
            <td>2009/10/09</td>
            <td>$1,200,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>42</td>
            <td>2010/12/22</td>
            <td>$92,575</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2010/11/14</td>
            <td>$357,650</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>2011/06/07</td>
            <td>$206,850</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Fiona Green</td>
            <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td>2010/03/11</td>
            <td>$850,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Shou Itou</td>
            <td>Regional Marketing</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>2011/08/14</td>
            <td>$163,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Michelle House</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Sidney</td>
            <td>37</td>
            <td>2011/06/02</td>
            <td>$95,400</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Suki Burks</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>53</td>
            <td>2009/10/22</td>
            <td>$114,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
            <td>Technical Author</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/05/07</td>
            <td>$145,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
            <td>Team Leader</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>2008/10/26</td>
            <td>$235,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Martena Mccray</td>
            <td>Post-Sales support</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>46</td>
            <td>2011/03/09</td>
            <td>$324,050</td>
        </tr>
       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to something like on the attached image (also on the given link). Any idea?

Comment: Check my edited code.. I have added the checkbox with the text as per your image.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but interestingly although there is no error on console, no element is seen on the toolbar. Could you please test it jsfiddle and then inform me?

Comment: If you think the answer is helpful, up vote would be really appreciated. About the testing, I have added the same locally and its working fine. If you can setup it on some live URL, it would be helpful us to solve it for you. :)

Comment: It is really useful and I created a Jsfiddle on https://jsfiddle.net/ycowoond/ We are really so close to the solution and I would be appreciated if you help me to solve the problem. **1)** I need to remove the Checkbox column and just a single checkbox on the toolbar. **2)** I need to display also records/page section that is decsribed with **dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',** but I cannot combine with **"dom": '<"toolbar">frtip'**. Any idea?

Comment: Perfect!!! I was trying to solve the problem and finally see that I have to use **$('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);** in the success of AJAX call. Thanks a lot...

Comment: I managed to align horizontally the all of the three element (page size, checkbox and Search) **"dom": 'lf<"toolbar">tip',**.

Comment: Any ide about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571553/jquery-datatable-individual-column-searching-on-table-header) question?

Comment: @ClintEastwood Let me see. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here I solved your problem.

Please check demo :https://jsfiddle.net/dipakthoke07/zeacozyc/4/

Hope this help you !

Thanks.

Comment: @Clint Eastwood i have solve this problem as your requirement which is shown in the image.you can check the demo. Thanks

Comment: Thanks but there is no difference between the answers and Viradiya answered first :) Thanks...

Comment: Not very helpful you just solving his problem, explain how you did it, what you did differently. low quality repsonse.